# How to import c_einsum using pip?

Tags: python, pip

I have installed everything `scipy`, `numpy`+mkl

Now when I want to import the following modules

```
import scipy
scipy.test()
```

it returns me the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'c_einsum'

Please help me. I am using python 3.5.2 32bit for my 64bit windows